# I do not see PGDATA and I am running a postgres instance. Should I?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, environment-variables

I run a search across both my user and the admin of the Postgres instance for anything like "PG" and do not see anything.  It leads to me to wonder if I am understanding documentation regarding Postgres environment variables such as PGDATA referenced such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045859/postgres-cannot-see-my-pgdata-environment-variable).

Perhaps I am ignorant on relevant updates or navigating the Linux system other than that I think my question still stands hence my question. I do not see PGDATA and I am running a Postgres instance. Should I?

[image]

Thanks!
John

Comment: if you did not set env vars, you dont see it. some OSes do it for you I guess

Comment: @VaoTsun So they are manually configured for additional functionality; is that a correct interpretation of how things work?

Comment: better knowing guys could tell better. by me tonight, the order is this: `later options -> earlier options -> os env -> config-> default`.

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry for being dense... what does "later options" and "earlier options" mean

Comment: well, I meant `-o option=val1 -o option=val2` will set option to `val2`